# Custom listview in fragment error

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-studio, android-fragments

I am new to Fragment in android and I create a simple list of state in fragment but it gives an error.

Here is my `list_item.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mytitle"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

here is my list_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/list"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/empty"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my Getter and setter

```
public class RowItem {
    private String title;

    public RowItem(String title)
    {
        this.title=title;
    }


    public String getTitle()
    {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle()
    {
        this.title=title;
    }
}
```

Here is my CustomAdapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    List<RowItem> rowItems;

    CustomAdapter(Context context,List<RowItem> rowItems)
    {
        this.context=context;
        this.rowItems=rowItems;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return rowItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return rowItems.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return rowItems.indexOf(getItem(i));
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        if (view==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,null);
        }

        TextView txtTitle=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mytitle);
        RowItem row_pos=rowItems.get(i);
        txtTitle.setText(row_pos.getTitle());
        return view;
    }
}
```

and finally MyListFragment class

```
public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment
{

    CustomAdapter customAdapter;
    private List<RowItem> rowItems;
    public MyListFragment()
    {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment,container,false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        //data
        getStateData();

        customAdapter=new CustomAdapter(getActivity(),rowItems);
        setListAdapter(customAdapter);

    }

    //state web service data
    private void getStateData()
    {
        final ProgressDialog pd=ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(),"Loading State","Please wait",false);

        StringRequest stateRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://resalerental.com/webservice/findstate.php"
                , new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                pd.dismiss();
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                getStateSpinner(response);

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                pd.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        RequestQueue stateQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        stateQueue.add(stateRequest);
    }

    private void getStateSpinner(String state)
    {
        ParseJson parseJson=new ParseJson(state);
        parseJson.parseState();

        rowItems=new ArrayList<RowItem>();

       for (int i=0;i<ParseJson.state_name.length;i++)
       {
           RowItem Item=new RowItem(ParseJson.state_name[i]);

           rowItems.add(Item);
       }
    }

}
```

Above is example given on a website. When i want to call this `MyFragmentList` using `FragmentManager` it give me error that wrong argument type pass.

Here how i call

```
MyListFragment myListFragment=new MyListFragment();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,myListFragment).commit();
```

Kindly suggest me what i do.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please paste your error also

Comment: whenever i call using FragmentManager it give me error that wrong argument type pass

Comment: share your logcat logs as well

Comment: can you show where you have called and which parameters you have passed while adding this fragment

Comment: your might be using getFragmentManager()
 instead of  getSupportFragmentManager()

Comment: Please past your call to ListFragment part code

Comment: I update the question

Comment: Check your fragment import.

Comment: I also use getSupportFraggmentManager but error remain same..

Comment: import `android.support.v4.Fragment` and then use `getSupportFraggmentManager()`

Comment: ok let me try @Piyush

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `getFragmentManager()` with `getSupportFragmentManager()` like in your code:

```
                MyListFragment myListFragment=new MyListFragment();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,myListFragment).commit();
```

if you use `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, you must use `getSupportFragmentManager()` for Fragment Manager and vice versa if you use `android.app.FragmentManager;` you must use `import android.app.Fragment;` for Fragment.

Comment: Actually i call this inside a Fragment Activity.....and i use getSupportFragmentManager but error remain same for that also ...thanks

Comment: i use  **FragmentManager fragmentManager=getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,myListFragment).commit();**

Comment: check your import

Comment: i import this **import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;**

Comment: not in logcat whennever i want to call this LIstFragment inside a Fragmenr class It give me error that wrong argument type found

Comment: check fragment import in your MyListFragment extends Fragment

Comment: i got what error i did...ListFragment import wrong ...thanks for your time